# Find the orthonormal matrix of the unit vector

Tags: linear-algebra

Studying for my finals in Linear algebra. In one of the tests I have the following question:

> Let $\underline{u}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be the unit vector. Find a diagonalizing orthonormal matrix $P$ and a diagonal matrix of eigenvalues $A$ so $\underline{u}\cdot\underline{u}^T=PAP^T$.

In other words, I need to find the spectral decomposition. I'm stuck over this basic question over a hour now and I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Think about what the matrix $u u^\mathrm{t}$ does. (Forgive me for not writing the bar below $u$). It is a projection operator. For any vector $v$, the vector $uu^\mathrm{t} v$ is just $u$ scaled by $u\cdot v$. The component of $v$ parallel to $u$ is retained; everything else is discarded.

If $w_2, w_3, \ldots, w_n$ are unit vectors such that $(u,w_2,\ldots,w_n)$ is an orthonormal basis, then relative to that basis the matrix $uu^\mathrm{t}$ looks like

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots& \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0
\end{bmatrix}.$$

The change of basis matrix $P$ is equal to
$$[u, w_1, w_2, \ldots, w_n];$$
this notation means the first column of $P$ is $u$, the second column is $w_1$, etc. When you multiply out $PAP^\mathrm{t}$ you will find that it equals $uu^\mathrm{t}$.